# UK Visit Visa Refusal for attending a fully funded summit

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, proof-provenance-of-funds

I have been refused visitor visa for a fully funded trip on the following grounds:
[image]

[image]

Comment: i need quick help as only 14 working days are left till the summit

Comment: IMHO best to forget about re-applying. A new application after a refusal will attract extra scrutiny, making it pretty unlikely you’d get a decision within the timeframe you need, even if you can satisfy the refusal reasons.

Comment: If the summit is fully funded, why did you say you needed to spend 500 pounds on the trip?

Comment: Sorry to say, but re-applying wont help you in my opinion. There are several reasons Since your rejection is based on the financial situation. You cannot change your financial situation in 15 days. The general rule to find out that that am I capable for the UK visa is to show 1/4 as an expense of the total ending balance. UK visa officers are very much consider financial status of the person.

Comment: i had erroneously written that i will spend 500 gbp....can i re-apply while saying that i would be spending 150 gbp which is 1/4th of ending balance? this is also justifiable as the entire trip is funded and 150 gbp would be an appropriate amount for keeping on the safe side

Comment: the sponsors are ready to pay for a priority visa

Comment: can you guide further? @Person321

Comment: @ffaisal There’s nothing to stop you from re-applying and stating a lower expenditure figure than in the original application. But doing so risks giving the impression that you’re just massaging the finances to try to get the visa approved, so you’d need to give a credible explanation of why £150 is suddenly enough when previously it was £500. Bear in mind that there is no general rule of 1/4, contrary to an earlier comment - the UK does not include such limits in its immigration rules for visitors.

Comment: There is not general rule for 1/4 of total income "Correct". But they do consider these facts when reviewing the application of the third world country. If you really into applying for again. You can justify this 150 pounds now for visiting attractions only and travelling fares. With the explanation that now your sponsor is going to support you more. I applied the UK visa after reading this hidden official hidden UK Guide. https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/827480/Visit-guidance-v9.0ext.pdf

Comment: You also need to account for the unexplained deposit of 17 Feb - that looks like something called 'Funds Parking' which is a no-no.